# 「オーディオの警告を視覚的に表示する」の変更をPowershellから実行したい

Tags: windows, powershell

使用中の環境はWindows10です。
設定 > 簡単操作 > オーディオ > 「オーディオの警告を視覚的に表示する」（[Windows を聞きやすくする](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/windows-%E3%82%92%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8D%E3%82%84%E3%81%99%E3%81%8F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-9c18cfdc-63be-2d47-0f4f-5b00facfd2e1#bkmk_visualalerts&WindowsVersion=Windows_10)）
の変更をPowershellから実行しようとしています。

変更は以下のレジストリに記録されることはわかっています。

```
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2877195124-415269717-4107617414-1001\Control Panel\Accessibility\SoundSentry]
"WindowsEffect"="0～3"
```

- 設定で変更すれば値はすぐに反映されレジストリに書き込まれます。
- しかし、レジストリを直接変更しても設定は反映されません。
- 再起動するとレジストリは再読み込みされ値が反映されます。

このような場合、「SendMessageTimeout」などの関数で更新を反映すると思われます。
具体的な反映方法がわかる方はおりませんでしょうか。

以下はレジストリを変更するPowershellのスクリプトです。

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS
$RegPath = "HKU:\S-1-5-21-2877195124-415269717-4107617414-1001\Control Panel\Accessibility\SoundSentry"
$RegKey = "WindowsEffect"
$CurrentRegKeyValue = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name $RegKey).WindowsEffect
$RegKeyValue = "3"
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath -name $RegKey -Value $RegKeyValue
```

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
なるほど！設定（メモリ内のみ）を変更する方法があったのですね。  
レジストリも変更すれば永続的にできるなど使い分けもできますね。  
こちらの方が都合が良いので非常に助かりました。  
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 再起動後も設定を有効にするためには、`SystemParametersInfo`呼び出しの際に`SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE`を設定してください。サンプルコード修正しておきました。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
関数に関しては私ももう少し勉強してみます。
サンプルまで修正していただき感謝いたします。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

レジストリ更新では即座に反映されません。User32.dllの[SystemParametersInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa)を使うことで即座に反映されるようになります。

実際に設定する方法について[SOUNDSENTRYW structure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-soundsentryw)を参考にしてください。

サンプル

```
# C#コードのインポート
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class NativeMethods
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
        var soundSentry = new SOUNDSENTRYW();
        uint size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SOUNDSENTRYW));
        soundSentry.cbSize = size;
        var result = NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSOUNDSENTRY, size, ref soundSentry, 0);
        if (result)
        {
            soundSentry.iWindowsEffect = 3;
            result = NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSOUNDSENTRY, size, ref soundSentry, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
        }
    }
    const uint SPI_GETSOUNDSENTRY = 0x0040;
    const uint SPI_SETSOUNDSENTRY = 0x0041;
    const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    
    internal struct SOUNDSENTRYW
    {
       public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint iFSTextEffect;
        public uint iFSTextEffectMSec;
        public uint iFSTextEffectColorBits;
        public uint iFSGrafEffect;
        public uint iFSGrafEffectMSec;
        public uint iFSGrafEffectColor;
        public uint iWindowsEffect;
        public uint iWindowsEffectMSec;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string lpszWindowsEffectDLL;
        public uint iWindowsEffectOrdinal;
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
        uint uiAction,
        uint uiParam,
        ref SOUNDSENTRYW pvParam,
        uint fWinIni
        );
}
"@

# C#コードの呼び出し。
[NativeMethods]::Execute()
```